# Grafana - How to import/copy just ONE graph of a big Dashboard A to a Dashboard B?

Tags: grafana

a small question regarding dashboards and graphs in Grafana please.

**How to import/copy just ONE graph of a big Dashboard A to a Dashboard B?**

By that, I mean I do not want to import the entire dashboard, I do not want to clone the entire dashboard.

Just want to select one particular interesting graph from a dashboard A, to copy to my own dashboard.

So far, I only tried cloning the entire dashboard, then removing one by one those I do not need (which is all of them except the one I need, and I believe this is not the right way to do it)

Is there a smarter way, which allow to copy/import only one graph of a dashboard please?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

3 hacky options based on grafana version.

1. Copy the graph json from dashboard json and paste in another graph and then move it accordingly from dashboard.
2. Panel > Inspect > Panel Json . Copy from there and paste in another graph.
3. If you hit the panel menu then the small menu icon in the panel menu, then Panel JSON, copy JSON, then in the other dashboard add panel. Go to the panel json view and paste the panel json.

Comment: this worked best for me, it also is the only method if say you are trying to copy a panel that you have read only access to!

Answer (score 14):

I found even a simpler way. Go to dashboard-1 (source dashboard from where you want to copy). In panel dropdown, there is a `copy` option under `More`. click it:

[image]

Now go to dashboard-2 (destination where you want to copy this panel). Click on Add panel, there is an option to paste copied panel:

[image]